# Angular stepper: Show a pop up on changing steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular and Material. I have a stepper and I want to show a dialog message before changing step in order to ask the user if he wants to change step or not. The probleme is that the step is changing before of showing the pop up and the user's answer. Yout can find my exemple here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-material-stepper-mok1em?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Bellow you can see the function that is called to change step:

```
public onStepChange(event: any, stepper:MatStepper): void { 
    //in the stepper we have the data of current step and in the event of the clicked step  
    console.log('Current step ' + stepper.selectedIndex + " next step " + event.selectedIndex);

          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogMessageN2Component, {
            width: '500px',
            height: '500px',
            data: {},
          });
          dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed' + JSON.stringify(result));
            if (result.data === 'no') {
              console.log("no");
              stepper.selectedIndex = event.selectedIndex; //go to clicked step
            }
            if (result.data === 'yes') {
              console.log("yes");
               stepper.selectedIndex = stepper.selectedIndex; // stay to the same step
              
            }
          });
      
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that the stepper goes to the next step before that your popup is opened because you're opening your popup inside the stepChage event that is called when you click on a button with a matStepperNext directive.
You can make it work by using a custom click event in your next buttons instead of a matStepperNext directive as shown below :

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="false" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button (click)="goToNextStep()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="goToNextStep()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    You are now done.
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

and your goToNextStep method will contain:

```
  goToNextStep(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogMessageN2Component, {
      width: '500px',
      height: '500px',
      data: {},
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed' + JSON.stringify(result));
      if (result.data === 'yes') {
        console.log('yes');
        this.stepper.next();
      }
    });
  }
```

And don't forget to add `@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;` in your component.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I need to show the pop up on changing the steps of the stepper and not use other buttons.

Comment: You can't show the pop up before changing the steps by clicking on the steps headers, because in the source code of the matStepperHorizontal, the event click on the matStepHeader selects the step you clicked on. You can see that here [link](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/stepper/stepper-horizontal.html) on line 4. I suggest you to find another way to move from one step to another.